# PHPExcel : Reading cell values with rangetoArray() function and apply sum formula

Tags: phpexcel

I'm trying to read the cell formulas with rangetoArray() function and then there is array values return i want to sum it with the phpexcel library when this function read the range values.

```
include 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
include 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php'

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($uploadedFile);

$cellValues = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A1:A2');
```

//Basically i'm doing this for sum values in for each loop .. but it is custom created. i want PHPExcel Library Function for SUM and other Mathmatic Operations.

```
foreach ($cellValues as $cell) {
    foreach ($cell as $finalValue) {
        $sumVal += $finalValue;
    }
}
```

//I want to read value through rangetoArray('A1:A5'); like this and automatic sum it with some PHPExcel Library function / method.

Thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense to me. What problem are you having doing this? Is rangeToArray() returning the data correctly from the spreadsheet? Do you have formulae in the worksheet to do the SUM? Are you trying to sum values in your own PHP code? What are you getting as a result? What are you expecting to get? Please clarify?

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply , Bascially i'm trying to read the values in PHPExcel through rangetoArray('A1:A2'); then array will be return to me after that i want to sum both values through PHPExcel library function.

Comment: So you loop through the values in that array, and sum them... what code are you using for that loop?

Comment: include 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

  include 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php'

  $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($uploadedFile);

  $cellValues = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A1:A2');
  
//Basically i'm doing this for sum values in for each loop .. but it is custom created. i want PHPExcel Library Function for SUM and other Mathmatic Operations.

  foreach ($cellValues as $cell) {

            foreach ($cell as $finalValue) {


                $sumVal += $finalValue;
            }
        }

Comment: So create a cell that has '=SUM(A1:A2)' as a formula, and then do a getCalculatedValue() on that cell.... there's plenty of examples of formulae provided

Comment: And rangeToArray() returns a 2d array of rows and cells, not a 1d array

Comment: Thanks for your replay again ,

I dont want to create excel sheet and cell for just  this process i want some process like after rangetoArray('A1:A5')->doSum();

Thanks

Comment: In that case, you're going to have to modify the rangeToArray() method to return a custom object instead of an array (SPLHeao might be a useful alternative), and write a doSum() method for that custom object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option #1**

Create a formula, assigning to a dummy cell (A1 in this case, though it doesn't change the value of cell A1 in any way), and using the calculation engine to execute that formula:

```
$sumFormula = '=SUM(A1:B2)';
$rangeSum = PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->calculateFormula(
    $sumFormula, 
    'A1', 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')
);
var_dump($rangeSum);
```

**Option #2**

Call the SUM() function directly from your own code, passing the result of the toArray() method to the function:

```
$rangeSum = PHPExcel_Calculation_MathTrig::SUM(
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A1:B2')
);
var_dump($rangeSum);
```

**Option #3**

Create your own class which will take the result of a fromArray() call, with a doSum() method:

```
class mySummer{
    protected $_cellArray;

    public function __construct(array $cells = array()) {
        $this->_cellArray = PHPExcel_Calculation_Functions::flattenArray($cells);
    }

    public function doSum(){
        return array_sum($this->_cellArray);
    }

}


$summer = new mySummer(
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A1:B2')
);
var_dump($summer->doSum());
```

Comment: Thanks Mark Baker !

You are amazing. you solve my issue. I have 2 more question but i will post these question to you after some days or time. Currently Please tell last thing . Sum calculation is done . if i want 3 calculation more. 1. count formula, 2. if count formula, 3. min / max value formula.

Thanks
Adil

Comment: You can use exactly the same methods as shown above: the Excel formulae (e.g. `=MAX(A1:B2)`) for option #1; using the appropriate calcengine function as per option #2 (PHPExcel functions are listed for each Excel function in /Documentation/FunctionListByName.txt or /Documentation/FunctionListByCategory.txt or online at https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation%20Calculation%20Engine%20Supported%20Functions ; or use your own class methods as per option #3

Comment: Hi Again,
your solution is work for me but it is only working with only integer values without dot numeric values. like 1234 is the number so your solution will sum it but if values is 1234.0 or 1234.00 your solution return 0 zero please help.

Comment: All three solutions should work with floating point numbers as well as with integers.... check the values returned by rangeToArray() to ensure that they are valid PHP numbers.... (e.g. not formatted with a comma as a decimal separator)

Comment: yes these are not numbers in excel sheet but what i do if user upload excel sheet so how can i convert first in numbers after reading the cells and what about decimal values.

Comment: You're beginning to lose me again.... if they're not numbers, then what do you expect a sum of the values to return? What are the values in the cells?

Comment: sorry about the above comments maybe i couldn't understand you the exact problem. my problem is if someone added in $1234 , $1234.00, $1234.000 in sheet so it is not a number so the current solution will not work in this case and return 0, is there any way to convet these kind of values in numbers. for correct functioning. & what about decimal values?

Comment: PHPExcel doesn't provide any function to handle that conversion if it's a genuine Excel file, because the Excel readers process the values exactly as they are held in the Excel file. If it's a CSV file load or similar, then the AdvancedValueBinder can be used to convert them to a numeric value, and set the appropriate monetary format. If you are loading Excel files, you could possibly do a loop through the cells after loading, feeding the values to the advancedValueBinder manually to convert them.... or train your users to use Excel properly :)

Comment: Thanks You Much Sir i have last question for you how can i get full column value like if i point A1 into rangetoarray('A1') then full column values return which is like from A1 to A100 to A200 and so on until values not end. bascially get A1 column and get all A1 values till end of column.

Comment: `rangeToArray('A1:A100')`.... you can use the worksheet's `getHighestRow()` or `getHighestDataRow()` method to identify how many rows exist

Comment: getHighestRow() & getHighestDataRow() returns only Cell coordinates like A is the column and 1 is the row where data is inserted. i want to return of A1 coordinator cells all values into array like.

  | A1  | B1 | C1 |
1 | 500 |200 |200 |
2 | 600 |300 |100 |
3 | 400 |500 |400 |

if i enter A1 in somefunction('A1') so function return me array(500, 600, 400).

Thanks
Adil

Comment: This is basic PHP string concatenation: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A1:A' . $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow())`

Comment: Thanks i got the solution through this but this is for your consideration. when if some column have 5 cell values and some columns have 10 cell values when you use this getHighestRow(); so it will return array with 5 actual values and 5 blanks values because 10 is the highest row in that case zero isn't effect in sum but maybe in other formulas zero or blank value can be effect. 
Thanks for your full support my question is answer by your Mark Baker Sir, so my question is closed now.
Thanks

Comment: In that case, if there's any likelihood of empty trailing rows, use `getHighestDataRow()` rather than `getHighestRow()`. But PHPExcel is a library for you to use, not a fully-fledged solution for every conceivable MS Excel spreadsheet

Comment: Thanks Sir Again You are the best man for learning PHPExcel library fully.

Comment: Thanks Sir Your the Best Person to learn fully PHPExcel Library. If i have more queries then i will add comments on this question or i will put new question for you.

Comment: Hi Sir,
I uploaded the CSV file and convert into excel but the calculation engine not working it returns me zero every time what to do?

Comment: Hi Sir, After a long time i'm asking the question how to load excel sheet with column and number sorting wise by default let suppose i have 100 value in A1 cell and 1000 in A2 cell when i will run function sort_order_by_column_name(A, Desc) then A2 value will come up to A1 and A1 value to will move to A2. is this possible in 
PHPExcel Library.
Thanks

Comment: PHPExcel won't sort the values for you, retrieve the values to an array and then sort that array

Comment: Thanks Sir,
Actually I'm asking that How to sort max value to cell A1. Suppose I have 1000 in A1, 2000 in A2 next time same file i uploaded and i changes the values A2 is 3000 but when i load excel it shows me 3000 on top of A column. 
Thanks

Comment: I'd guess you could use rangeToArray() to read all the values into an array, sort the array, then use fromArray() to reset the cell values again

Comment: Hi,
Sir , did your library support full languages like if i load any files in memory and convert into excel 5 then it will save it with correct language and special chracters. I have issue with danish language i think. Please give advise what to do?

Comment: Use UTF-8 for everything, and you shouldn't have any language problems

Comment: I'tried to arrange the values up down from rangetoarray & fromarray but i couldn't find example please show some examples.

Comment: Please ask as a proper question, rather than as a comment against this question... that way I can answer without having to make another comment, and the details are visible to anyone else that wants help with a similar problem