# Iterating through rangeToArray() in PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I have Excel sheets that I need to perform calculations with.
I am using PHPSpreadsheet to read and write, as PHPExcel is now deprecated.

The problem I am experiencing is in getting values from a specific column to perform calculations.

After going through the documentation, I found that I can use the rangeToArray() function to retrieve the values.
My code looks like this:

```
$inputFiletype = 'Xlsx';
$inputFileName = './helloworld.xlsx';
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($inputFileName);

$find_val = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('K1:K5');
```

This, according to the documentation, creates an array ($find_vals).
However, when I attempt to loop through the array to view the values, I get an 'Array to string Conversion' notice, with the output of "Array".

If I use var_dump, I get the following:

```
array(5) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> float(1) } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> float(2) } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> float(3) } [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> float(4) } [4]=> array(1) { [0]=> float(5) } }
```

I have tried the following loop codes:

```
for($i=0; $i<=4; $i++) {
    echo (string)$find_val[$i];
}
```

as well as

```
foreach($find_val as $vals) {
    echo $vals;
}
```

I have also tried the following which changed the result a little:

```
for($i=0; $i<=4; $i++) {
    echo (string)$find_val[$i][$i];
}
```

This output one value, and gave me Undefined Offset errors for the other 4 iterations.

How would I be able to successfully iterate through a rangeToArray value using the PhpSpreadsheet API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770580/phpexcel-reading-cell-values-with-rangetoarray-function-and-apply-sum-formul)

```
foreach ($find_val as $cell) {
    foreach ($cell as $finalValue) {
        echo $finalValue . "\r\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly. Can you explain why this works?

Comment: In short, **rangeToArray** returns an array of arrays which you need to transverse. If your ever in doubt, you should simply print the resulting array `print_r($find_val); exit();` to see it's structure.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw your post now. Have you tried this?
You are almost there.

```
foreach($sheetData as $vals) {
    echo $vals[0];
}
```